# How can I git diff local changes to a different branch?

Tags: git, branch, diff

I have a repository checked out to some (unknown) tag ( Not currently on any branch. ) and with some local changes not checked in to the index. When I run git diff on a file it gives me some changes, which I am unsure with respect to which commit they are. I want to get the diff to the top of a given branch. Is there a git diff command for it? something like:

```
git diff myLocalFile myRemoteBranch
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify a particular file with `diff` by using `--` at the end of the command.

Also, you can use the `HEAD` pointer to specify where you currently are, rather than having to specify the tag you are on.

Example:

```
git diff HEAD..myRemoteBranch -- relative/path/to/myLocalFile
```

Or, more simply:

```
git diff myRemoteBranch -- relative/path/to/myLocalFile
```

Also, if you actually want to compare against a "remote" branch, you should probably reference that branch using a `remote` like:

```
git fetch # retrieve latest from server
git diff origin/myRemoteBranch -- relative/path/to/myLocalFile
```

Comment: I'm puzzled as this does not seem to detect any changes, even though there are some... The local changes are not checked in to the index though

Comment: Ah...you may need to `commit` first to see the diff of your changes against another branch.
I would recommend creating a new branch from your current point (`get checkout -b myBranch`), staging (`add`), and committing (`commit`) and then use the `diff` command to see the changes.

Comment: Bingo! Without the HEAD.. it detects the changes against the given branch.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question; the question is about how to do that without commiting/checking things into the index.

Answer (score 0):

Git has a tool built in for that:

```
git diff-index myRemoteBranch myLocalFile
```

It outputs in "raw" format by default, use `-p` to get a patch just like `git diff` does by default:

```
git diff-index -p myRemoteBranch myLocalFile
```